# Easy to use viewer for shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, software-recommendations

I have some shapefiles with the following extension. I am not sure what is the simplest way to visualize them. What is the most popular free software to visualize these files?

- cpg
- dbf
- prj
- sbn
- sbx
- shp
- shx

Comment: Simple answer: QGIS - https://qgis.org/ - should also work with Google Earth.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS (open source GIS) for desktop software where you can edit, map, and do anything you want with the data.

Online if you just want to view the data and do simple edits, https://mapshaper.org/.
Just drag and drop the files to the site. If you need to see context behind the shapefile, hit Basemap and pick Map or Satellite to see the area with your data.